# openfiledialog in webpart

Tags: development, web-part, wss-3.0, windows-server

How to implement openfile dialog in a webpart ?
OpenFileDialog class could not be accessed in webpart.
Is there any other way to achieve this ?
[image: File Browse Dialog]

Comment: what exactly are you trying todo? open a file from a site? or save to a site?

Comment: @aliSharepoint I want to upload a document to the site. The user should be able to browse the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahh ok, your looking for fileupload:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx

> Displays a text box control and a browse button that enable users to
>   select a file to upload to the server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454491(v=office.12).aspx

> This programming task shows how to upload a file from a local folder
>   to a folder on a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation site. The task uses
>   the EnsureParentFolder method to ensure that the destination folder
>   exists.

**EDIT**

i understand that your using a webpart instead of aspx page! but what you can do in aspx you can do in .cs , so in your case:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    //create the textbox file object
    HtmlInputFile tbuploadfile = new HtmlInputFile();
    //add the newly created HtmlInputFile to the controls
    //when you run the code add it to the page you should see that new control
    this.Controls.Add(tbuploadfile);
}
```

so just do the same as above for what its asking for in the aspx but convert it to .cs instead... its simple todo as above :) . wss 3.0 is a pain the ***

**END EDIT**

scroll to the bottom of the page to show you how its done ;)

another option

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95954/Sharepoint-WebPart-for-Programmatically-Uploading

Comment: Actually I dont have _.aspx_ file in my project.
In the second link it is specified to add `HtmlInputFile` to the form on .aspx page.

I'm developing sharepoint webpart and my webpart inherits from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart`.

Comment: changed my answer, checkout the update :)

Comment: glad to see you got it working