# User profile picture in visual web part

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

I want to make user upload the profile picture in my web part, I searched over the internet how to accomplish this?

I found the [this](http://matthewyarlett.blogspot.in/2013/06/uploading-and-resizing-images-to.html) post which describes how to get it.

My code is:

```
void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            userMessage.Text = String.Empty;
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            previewImage.ImageUrl = null;
            previewImage.Visible = false;
            if (!fileBrowser.HasFile)
            {
                userMessage.Text = "Please select a user to associate this image with before clicking Upload.";
                return;
            }
            //Check the file is less than 4MB
            int fileSize = fileBrowser.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            if (fileSize > 4000000)
            {
                userMessage.Text += String.Format("File Size Exceeds 4MB. Choose a smaller file.");
                return;
            }

            String imageFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileBrowser.FileName);
            //Check the user has selected a jpg image
            if (imageFileExtension == null || imageFileExtension.ToLower() != ".jpg")
            {
                userMessage.Text += "The file you have selected is not in the right format. Please use a jpg image.";
                return;
            }

            var imageFileData = fileBrowser.FileBytes;
            using (var imageFileStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                imageFileStream.Write(imageFileData, 0, imageFileData.Length);
                //Before uploading the image to SharePoint, lets make sure resize the image if the width or height are greater than 300px.
                var imagePreview = ResizeImage(imageFileStream, 300, 300);
                SPList listExists = web.Lists.TryGetList("Img");
                SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();
                if (listExists == null)
                {
                    //...
                    return;
                }
                var v = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
                try
                {
                    var fileName = fileBrowser.FileName.Replace(" ", "-");
                    var urlpreview = String.Format("{0}/Img/{1}", web.Url, fileName);
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    web.Files.Add(urlpreview, imagePreview, true);
                    previewImage.ImageUrl = urlpreview;
                    previewImage.Visible = true;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    //..Do something
                }
                finally
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = v;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //...
        }

    }
    public byte[] ResizeImage(Stream fileData, int maxwidth, int maxheight)
    {
        using (var image = new Bitmap(fileData))
        {
            int adjustedWidth = image.Width;
            int adjustedHieght = image.Height;

            //Check the image is less than the maxwidth. If not, resize the image dimensions.
            if (adjustedWidth > maxwidth)
            {
                decimal ratio = Decimal.Divide(maxwidth, adjustedWidth);
                adjustedWidth = maxwidth;
                adjustedHieght = Convert.ToInt32(Decimal.Multiply(adjustedHieght, ratio));
            }
            //Now that we've adjusted the width, check the hieght is below the maximum hieght value
            if (adjustedHieght > maxheight)
            {
                decimal ratio = Decimal.Divide(maxheight, adjustedHieght);
                adjustedHieght = maxheight;
                adjustedWidth = Convert.ToInt32(Decimal.Multiply(adjustedWidth, ratio));
            }

            var resizedImage = new Bitmap(adjustedWidth, adjustedHieght);
            var g = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage);
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, adjustedWidth, adjustedHieght);
            g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, adjustedWidth, adjustedHieght);
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            const int quality = 90;
            var encoderParameters = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, (long)quality);
            resizedImage.Save(ms, GetImageCodeInfo("image/jpeg"), encoderParameters);
            ms.Position = 0;
            var data = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Read(data, 0, (int)ms.Length);
            return data;
        }
    }

    public static ImageCodecInfo GetImageCodeInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] imageEncoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo imageCodeInfo in imageEncoders)
        {
            if (imageCodeInfo.MimeType.Equals(mimeType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return imageCodeInfo;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Changes made by me are:

`SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;` \ as it fetches the sub site.
`SPList listExists = web.Lists.TryGetList("Img");` \ As the name is `Img` in my subsite.
`var urlpreview = String.Format("{0}/Img/{1}", web.Url, fileName);`

All remaining code is same as in the post.

But I am getting the error at the line : `web.Files.Add(urlpreview, imagePreview, true);` that `There is no file with URL 'http://..../sites/test/communities/Img/tumblr_mprolrMaPP1qe983go1_500.jpg' in this Web.` (Communitites is sub site)

What am I missing? Is there another way to accomplish my requirement?

Comment: Everything *looks* fine, but I wonder if there is something breaking your `imagePreview` stream/byte array, SharePoint throws a weird error you try to upload a file that is zero-length (an empty file). Care to post the rest of your code?

Comment: Post Edited....

Comment: sir, did you find anything?

Answer (score 2):

please refer to my other post for uploading files to a list!

[openfiledialog in webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62996/openfiledialog-in-webpart)

just to make it clear, when uploading its using the url not the location of list! so goto your list and get the relative path and not the name of the list ;)

as an example i did this for client side app to upload to a sharepoint image document library

```
            string file = ofdlg.FileName;
            string fileTitle = ofdlg.SafeFileName;
            string relativepath = string.Format("{0}", "/PublishingImages/" + fileTitle);

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@file, FileMode.Open))
            {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, relativepath, fs, true);

                Uri filename = new Uri(@ImageUrl);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileInformation f = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, relativepath);
                using (fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\tempImagesPM\" + fileTitle, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    CopyToThis(f.Stream, fileStream);

                }
            }
```

as you can see im using the `openfiledialog` (winform) and uploading via `filestream`. The path is hard coded using relativepath (PublishingImages) followed by the name of file im uploading , so the url would be `http://mysite.com/PublishingImages/nameoffile`

in your case its similar, you need an asp.net version of `openfiledialog` (Stream/inputStream) to ge the file, add file from input stream using `FileStream` to the spsite or spweb using the method `site.Files.Add(destUrl, contents);` which takes the destination url and its bite array from the input steam!

once you have uploaded the image that you can go through the site and web object to show the new image within the webpart.

**EDIT**

for a full solution but done with console app (very easy to change) can be done like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles;

namespace UploadProfileImage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program prog = new Program();
            prog.UploadProfileImages();
        }

        private void UploadProfileImages()
        {

            // my site host url
            String url = "http://sp2010/profiles/host&quot;;
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    ProfileImagePicker profileImagePicker = new ProfileImagePicker();
                    InitializeProfileImagePicker(profileImagePicker, web);
                    SPFolder subfolderForPictures = GetSubfolderForPictures(profileImagePicker);

                    // repeat this block if you have more images and users
                    // your account name
                    String accountName = @"domain\administrator";
                    // path to image file
                    String imageFilePath = @"C:\Temp\AdminAvatar.jpg";
                    UploadPhoto(accountName, imageFilePath, subfolderForPictures, profileImagePicker);
                    SetPictureUrl(accountName, subfolderForPictures);
                    // repeat block finished

                }
            }
        }


        private void SetPictureUrl(string accountName, SPFolder subfolderForPictures)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting profile image for user '{0}'", accountName);

            SPSite site = subfolderForPictures.ParentWeb.Site;
            UserProfileManager userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(SPServiceContext.GetContext(site));
            UserProfile userProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(accountName);

            string fileNameWithoutExtension = GetFileNameFromAccountName(accountName);

            string pictureUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}_MThumb.jpg", site.Url, subfolderForPictures.Url, fileNameWithoutExtension);

            userProfile["PictureUrl"].Value = pictureUrl;
            userProfile.Commit();
        }


        private void UploadPhoto(string accountName, string imageFilePath, SPFolder subfolderForPictures, ProfileImagePicker profileImagePicker)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uploading image '{0}' for user '{1}'", imageFilePath, accountName);

            if (!File.Exists(imageFilePath) || Path.GetExtension(imageFilePath).Equals(".gif"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File '{0}' does not exist or has invalid extension", imageFilePath);
            }
            else
            {
                string fileNameWithoutExtension = GetFileNameFromAccountName(accountName);

                FileStream file = File.Open(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open);
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file);

                if (subfolderForPictures != null)
                {
                    // try casting length (long) to int
                    byte[] buffer = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);

                    int largeThumbnailSize = 0×90;
                    int mediumThumbnailSize = 0×60;
                    int smallThumbnailSize = 0×20;

                    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                    {
                        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream, true))
                        {
                            CreateThumbnail(bitmap, largeThumbnailSize, largeThumbnailSize, subfolderForPictures, fileNameWithoutExtension + "_LThumb.jpg");
                            CreateThumbnail(bitmap, mediumThumbnailSize, mediumThumbnailSize, subfolderForPictures, fileNameWithoutExtension + "_MThumb.jpg");
                            CreateThumbnail(bitmap, smallThumbnailSize, smallThumbnailSize, subfolderForPictures, fileNameWithoutExtension + "_SThumb.jpg");
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }


        private void InitializeProfileImagePicker(ProfileImagePicker profileImagePicker, SPWeb web)
        {
            Type profileImagePickerType = typeof(ProfileImagePicker);

            FieldInfo fi_m_objWeb = profileImagePickerType.GetField("m_objWeb", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            fi_m_objWeb.SetValue(profileImagePicker, web);

            MethodInfo mi_LoadPictureLibraryInternal = profileImagePickerType.GetMethod("LoadPictureLibraryInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (mi_LoadPictureLibraryInternal != null)
            {
                mi_LoadPictureLibraryInternal.Invoke(profileImagePicker, new object[] { });
            }
        }

        public SPFile CreateThumbnail(Bitmap original, int idealWidth, int idealHeight, SPFolder folder, string fileName)
        {
            SPFile file = null;

           // hack to get the Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles assembly
           Assembly userProfilesAssembly = typeof(UserProfile).Assembly;
           // or assuming you know all the details of the assembly
           // Assembly userProfilesAssembly = Assembly.Load(“Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c”);

           // UserProfilePhotos is internal class, 
           // so you cannot get it directly from Visual Studio             
            Type userProfilePhotosType = userProfilesAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfilePhotos");

           MethodInfo mi_CreateThumbnail = userProfilePhotosType.GetMethod("CreateThumbnail", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
           if (mi_CreateThumbnail != null)
           {
                file = (SPFile)mi_CreateThumbnail.Invoke(null, new object[] { original, idealWidth, idealHeight, folder, fileName });
            }

            return file;
        }

        private SPFolder GetSubfolderForPictures(ProfileImagePicker profileImagePicker)
        {
            SPFolder folder = null;

            Type profileImagePickerType = typeof(ProfileImagePicker);

            MethodInfo mi_GetSubfolderForPictures = profileImagePickerType.GetMethod("GetSubfolderForPictures", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (mi_GetSubfolderForPictures != null)
            {
                folder = (SPFolder)mi_GetSubfolderForPictures.Invoke(profileImagePicker, new object[] { });
            }

            return folder;
        }

        private string GetFileNameFromAccountName(string accountName)
        {
            string result = accountName;
            string charsToReplace = @"\/:*?""<>|";
            Array.ForEach(charsToReplace.ToCharArray(), charToReplace => result = result.Replace(charToReplace, '_'));
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

full description can be found here:

http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/how-to-upload-a-user-profile-photo-programmatically/